# ClassNotFoundException while trying to use slick codegen

Tags: java, scala, playframework, slick-3.0

I am trying to use a custom codegen for the purpose of acquiring DateTime types from mysql instead of Timestamp. I just couldn't make the sbt task to run with the custom code generator.

class is located at /project-root/app/com/my/name

```
val conf = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("conf/application.conf")).resolve()
slick <<= slickCodeGenTask

lazy val slick = TaskKey[Seq[File]]("gen-tables")
lazy val slickCodeGenTask = (sourceManaged, dependencyClasspath in Compile, runner in Compile, streams) map { (dir, cp, r, s) =>
  val outputDir = (dir / "slick").getPath
  val url = conf.getString("slick.dbs.default.db.url")
  val jdbcDriver = conf.getString("slick.dbs.default.db.driver")
  val slickDriver = conf.getString("slick.dbs.default.driver").dropRight(1)
  val pkg = "com.my.name"
  val user = conf.getString("slick.dbs.default.db.user")
  val password = conf.getString("slick.dbs.default.db.password")
  toError(r.run(s"$pkg.CustomCodeGenerator", cp.files, Array(slickDriver, jdbcDriver, url, outputDir, pkg, user, password), s.log))
  val fname = outputDir + s"/$pkg/Tables.scala"
  Seq(file(fname))
}
```

it always gives the same exception below when i try to run `sbt gen-tables`

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.my.name.CustomCodeGenerator
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sbt.classpath.ClasspathFilter.loadClass(ClassLoaders.scala:59)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at sbt.Run.getMainMethod(Run.scala:72)
    at sbt.Run.run0(Run.scala:60)
    at sbt.Run.sbt$Run$$execute$1(Run.scala:51)
    at sbt.Run$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Run.scala:55)
    at sbt.Run$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Run.scala:55)
    at sbt.Run$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Run.scala:55)
    at sbt.Logger$$anon$4.apply(Logger.scala:84)
    at sbt.TrapExit$App.run(TrapExit.scala:248)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

when i try some built in java classes or default slick codegen class just to experiment it founds the class

i tried changing the order of this task in the build.sbt class but didn't solved

Comment: Had the same issue using slick codegen together with play. I solved it creating a sub project for the codegen stuff.

Comment: I did as you suggested, created a module and magically it now sees the class. Now there is another problem that nothing in that class seems like working but it should be at least import my custom fields. Still thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

Instead of
`dependencyClasspath in Compile`
use `fullClasspath in Compile`
see https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Classpaths.html

Comment: @Deliganli if you accept this answer I will flag another questions as duplicate so that it would point here (unless they accept first). Creating a subproject is more an hack than a real solution (even if it would technically work)